# EPPlus changing formatting when loading excel document from SSRS export

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer, epplus

I want to combine multiple excel documents (obtained by exporting from an SSRS report with different parameters), before emailing to a particular person. Each document needs to be a new worksheet in a 'master' document.

I have the following code - which works, except EPPlus seems to change all text formatting to have bold, italic and strike-through styling;

```
  DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7), endDate = DateTime.Today;
  List<EnAccount> accounts = GetAccounts(startDate, endDate);

    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        foreach (EnAccount account in accounts)
            using (MemoryStream reportStream = new MemoryStream(
                GetReport("REPORTSERVERPATH", "REPORTPATH", "EXCELOPENXML", new List<ReportParameter>() { new ReportParameter("AccountID", account.AccountID.ToString()), new ReportParameter("StartDate", startDate.ToShortDateString()), new ReportParameter("EndDate", endDate.ToShortDateString()) })
            ))
            using (ExcelPackage accountPackage = new ExcelPackage(reportStream))
                excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(account.AccountName, accountPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First());

        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray()))
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@email.com.au", "NAME"));
            message.From = new MailAddress("email2@email.com.au", "TEST");
            message.Subject = "SUBJECT";
            message.Body = "BODY.";
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(outputStream, "Report.xlsx"));

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("MAILCLIENT");
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help as to why it changes this formatting, and how i can get it to retain the original formatting?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about the excel tables you are merging.  Could you post some samples?

Comment: I don't think the data itself matters. It seems to be how SSRS exports it. I've worked around it by explicitly changing the font styles (e.g. accountPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First().Styles.Fonts[0].Bold = false, etc). This isn't ideal though. Heres an example of the data anyway: http://imgur.com/WEA3dCO

Comment: "I don't think the data itself matters. It seems to be how SSRS exports it."  Exactly.  The data is probably not the problem but something in the export from SSRS.  With example exports others could try to reproduce the problem and see if they can come up with a solutions. Unless someone else has dealt with the exact same issue and can provide an answer this is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you need to do this? Create a "main" report in SSRS. In this report, add two lists with subreports inside. then on the lists properties, add a page break before. If you then run the main report, it will have a report on each sheet.